# How to absolutely position HTML elements in a responsive way

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've spent two days going crazy about how to responsively position some html elements. Basically, the effect I'm trying to achieve is what this site exhibits before the stacking occurs for the Field Service Management and Intelligent Route Planning & Fleet Management sections:

https://workwave.com/

Both of these sections have two parts. On one side is an image that has a fixed pixel length, but shrinks in size at various break points. On the other side are an h1, p, and button element that remain in exactly the same position when the image shrinks in size. I've tried recreating this effect through absolutely positioning the elements that are contained together, but this solution doesn't work because the margin on one side has to be set so high that it eventually squeezes and pushes the html elements down too far.

How can I ensure that the html elements (h1, p, and button), remain unaffected when the image shrinks in size based on the media query? I greatly appreciate any insight.

The current code I have is:

```css
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #de6426 !important;
    border-color: #de6426 !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: hsla(20, 74%, 41%, 1) !important;
    border-color: hsla(20, 74%, 41%, 1) !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
     background-color: hsla(20, 74%, 41%, 1) !important;
     border-color: hsla(20, 74%, 41%, 1) !important;
     color: #fff;
  }

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 792px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
  }

  .fleet {
      width: 400px;
  }

.items-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #0f2c4d;
}

.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin-left: 50px; 
    min-width: 390px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

  h1 {
      margin: 0;
      color: #008ad1;
  }

  p {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 6rem;
    margin-right: 6rem;
  }

  .btn {
      height: 30px;
      width: 80px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-family: Carnas-Light;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="items-wrapper">
                        <div class="items"> 
                            <h1>Intelligent Route Planning & Fleet Management</h1>
                            <p>Improve efficiency and scalability of fleet operations through dynamic planning, intelligent route optimization and more.</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                        </div> 
                </div>
                    <img class="fleet" src="https://i.imgur.com/UakU07V.png" alt="Mountain View">
        </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you resize that page, the field management section below 900px stacks the text content on top of the image, so I am not clear about the final result you want.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i just mean before the stacking occurs. the effect i'm trying to achieve is the exact same as on this site https://workwave.com/ for the Field Service Management and Intelligent Route Planning & Fleet Management before the stacking occurs .

Comment: i really appreciate you taking a look at this because it's driving me nuts that i can't precisely recreate the html elements positioning in-relation to the image before the stacking occurs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are adding too much HTML/CSS mark-up that is not really necessary here. Also if you wish to use a flexbox grid model, why (just ask yourself) using Bootstrap at the same time?

Right to the code. In the HTML sample just make the mark-up leaner and apply the flex in the outer container so that both the text elements and the image can be styled and scaled as you wish.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="items-wrapper">
            <h1>Intelligent Route Planning & Fleet Management</h1>
            <p>Improve efficiency and scalability of fleet operations through dynamic planning, intelligent route optimization and more.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
        </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="fleet" src="https://i.imgur.com/UakU07V.png" 
        alt="Mountain View">         
   </div>
</div>
```

Next onto your CSS file.

```
/* generic styles */

body {
margin: 0;
} 

h1 {
margin: 0;
color: #008ad1;
font-family: Carnas-Light;
}

p {
color: white;
margin-left: 6rem;
margin-right: 6rem;
}

.btn {
height: 30px;
width: 80px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
background-color: hsla(20, 74%, 41%, 1) !important;
border-color: hsla(20, 74%, 41%, 1) !important;
color: #fff;
}

/* Container Flex  */

.container {
width: 100%;
background-color: #0f2c4d;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-flow: nowrap;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
text-align: center; 
}

.items-wrapper, .img-wrapper{
 width: 50%;
}

.items-wrapper {
 padding: 10px;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 .container {
    display: block;
  }

 .items-wrapper, .img-wrapper{
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Note you can adjust the media query based on the viewport size you like. 
I have just set it to 600px to demonstrate the concept.

[See Proof of Concept in this JSBIN here](https://jsbin.com/raxohap/1/edit?css,output)

Comment: the bootstrap is to replicate the button. i appreciate the time you spent, but this in not the effect i'm trying to achieve. i know how to align two flex boxes next to each other. the real difficulty in this is how to re-size the image (which is a set pixel length based on the specific break point) on the right without impacting the size of the specific html elements (h1, p, button) like on this site https://workwave.com/

Comment: We are talking about two different implementations here for the same effect. The first two examples use the bootstrap grid model. Specifically, the classes in the above containers have their respective references to small and medium size view ports with an offset property to the right (left). However, the link above "workwave" achieves that effect with the `CSS background-image` property so you will need to move the current image to the CSS and experiment from there. I am still confused about the concurrent usage of flexbox AND Bootstrap together. That is probably off topic though.

Comment: Let me know how you get on with the Bootstrap grid or with the image uploaded through CSS; I will try to give this a shot again at a later stage

Comment: having the image uploaded through css doesn't make any difference. it's possible to just target the img in the css.

Comment: Have you sorted things yet? Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: if you're able to look at the website workwave.com and know how to re-create the precise responsive layout format for the the Field Service Management and Intelligent Route Planning & Fleet Management sections, where the text remains absolutely positioned while the image snaps back i'd be intrigued.

Comment: As I have mentioned above, the effect is obtained by uploading the image as a CSS background. There is no way you can replicate that effect only using HTML without an image in your CSS file. For the first section there is also an image overlay placed there with `position absolute`. I am still trying to reproduce the effect though so will see.

Comment: i hope you're looking at the right section. it's not the first panel i'm talking about. i've already re-created that. it's the Field Service Management and Intelligent Route Planning section.